# Text underline by using ApplyPropertyValue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to underline the selected text by using textrange in ApplyProperyValue.
Here is my single line of code   :

```
new TextRange(start, end).ApplyPropertyValue(??, TextDecorations.Underline);
```

Comment: Okay, what's wrong with that code?

Comment: I am using "??" in property value argument, What should I replace it with ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass dependency property in there which is `Inline.TextDecorationsProperty` -

```
new TextRange(start, end).ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty,
                                                TextDecorations.Underline);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`TextRange.ApplyPropertyValue Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textrange.applypropertyvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) MSDN file, the [`TextRange.ApplyPropertyValue Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textrange.applypropertyvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method takes a [`DependencyProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and an [`Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
public void ApplyPropertyValue(
    DependencyProperty formattingProperty,
    Object value
)
```

You are probably looking for the [`Inline.TextDecorationsPropertyProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.inline.textdecorations%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Dependency Property.

```
new TextRange(start, end).ApplyPropertyValue(
    Inline.TextDecorationsProperty,
    TextDecorations.Underline);
```